# SSH in Browser GCP, Failing to connect

Tags: ssh, server, backend, instance, firewall

I have added my SSH to GCP (Public Key) , When trying to connect to a VM Instance (SSH in Browser) it fails to connect and gives the following errors,

As a resolution and following multiple online guides, I have created a firewall to allow for TCP 22 and so on, however, when I troubleshoot the following happens:

Connection Failed
We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22.

Please ensure that VM has a firewall rule that allows TCP ingress traffic from the IP range 0.0.0.0/0, port: 22.
In case you prefer to allow SSH connections for the narrower IP range, please consider using Identity-Aware-Proxy (IAP).

I disabled the firewalls, tried to modify IP sources, but still failing to access VM Instance, what am I missing?